# AdminLTE integrating in jhipster app

Tags: jhipster, adminlte

I had started with intention to bring UI of adminLTE into Jhipster gateway app. For this, I followed following steps:

1. getting repository from https://github.com/TwanoO67/bootstraping-ngx-admin-lte.
2. copying required dependency from package.json of AdminLTE to package.json of jhipster app. It downloaded adminLTE module in node_module folder.
3. copying source code, tweaking/changing, solving errors where ever required. 
   I could successfully bring the code from admin folder of adminLTE under jhipser app, and I could achieve the following result.

[image]

Now the problem is it is complaining about AdminLTE is not defined. AdminLTE is defined in script.js in "assets/js/scripts.js"

I am looking for ways to make this file available to my code in `any.component.ts`. One way I tried is, including in script tag in index.html and adding following line to CopyWebpackPlugin in wepack.common.js.

```
{ from: './src/main/webapp/assets', to: 'assets' }
```

This successfully loads the file in browser and init function in script.js also gets called. But then it complains about use of jQuery in script.js.

After fixing this, I think I would be successful in bringing the AdminLTE to jhipster app.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [jhipster-adminLTE](https://github.com/MHL3060/jhipster-adminLTE),it's jhipster admin lte theme with angular-dashboard-framework.

Comment: Answers that are just a single link are not great for this site. Since you took the time to answer an old question, why not take the time to give a brief synopsis of the relevant details here to make it a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to apply ngx-admin to a JHisper project. Since JHipster uses webpack to build but ngx-admin don't. But I did at last. I share my work on [my github](https://github.com/mehmetsunkur/jhipster-ngxadmin) you can follow the instructions. I hope it helps.